# Designing a service for reading files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3

**Conceptual Overview**

Store templated text files on the file system. Read text file into a templating service, get the string, send the email.

I have 2 services so far:

1. ITemplateService - this is the templating engine (accepts model and the string for templating).
2. IEmailService - Send email.

Can I have an example of how a file reader service would look, how I can mock or unit test it. Thanks.

I basically want to pass a path/filename to a method and let it read the file and return a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string filePath)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) returns the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You may also checkout [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/).